# VSLauncher starts wrong version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I have 3 versions of Visual Studio installed, and 3 projects that require a specific version. VSLauncher USED to look at the SLN or VCPROJ file and open the correct version of Visual Studio. Now it only starts the most recent version, regardless of the project.

Note that this has nothing to do with the commonly reported problem with beta versions of VS. none of the SLNs have ever been touched by a beta VS.

Comment: In what order did you install the different versions?

Comment: In order. 2005, then 2008, then 2010. I /think/ it was after that the 2010 version was installed that the trouble started, but I am not sure. it has been a while since I worked in the 2005 project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that the SLN files were subtly corrupted. Deleting the files and letting the appropriate version of VS recreate them resulted in a file that the diff tool thought was identical, but was exactly 3 bytes longer. I suspect the problem can be traced to a missing UTF-8 Byte Order Mark. Why VSLauncher is that picky is another question.

ADD: Yes, After opening the new file in a hex editor, I can say for certain that the problem was a missing BOM on the old file. This was tricky to spot because my diff tool apparently does not even see the BOM.

Comment: I had the exact same problem after manually editing a .sln file. The BOM was corrupted and the culprit was Textpad. Used Notepad instead which worked fine.

Answer (score 14):

I had this same issue. VS 2008 solutions opening in VS2010 when double clicked. This problem went away after first going into VS 2008 and using 'Restore File Associations' then right clicking on a 2008 solution file and choosing open with and pointing it to Version Selector. Prior to this they invariably opened in 2010. Very frustrating. Hope this helps.

```
Tools | Options | Environment | (big button marked Restore File Associations
```

Comment: Where in the labyrinth is "Restore File Associations"?

Comment: Funnily enough this restored the double click from explorer but not the 'from TFS'. Thanks Anyway

Comment: Just went to ".sln" file properties and changed default program to VS version selector.

Comment: I would upvote this 30000 times if I could! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JiveDadson In newer VS-es there is the "quick launch" (Ctrl+Q) search/command box, if you type "file associations" it will take you there.

Comment: Is there a way to run VSLauncher.exe in diagnostic mode?  I tried VSLauncher.exe --help, VSLauncher.exe -?, etc. and nothing worked, and I don't see any command line support.  It's a bit strange.  I thought the point of VSLauncher.exe was to let you choose Visual Studio version manually if you wanted?

Answer (score 5):

I also found, in Windows 7 Explorer, that I could right-click the sln, select Open with / Choose default program, then select Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector - it would open with VS2008 (as was appropriate) and from then on, double-clicking the sln file would cause VS2008 to launch.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 10 and Visual Studios 2017 and 2019:

1. Click Windows Start Button
2. Start Typing 'Default app settings'
3. Choose "Default app settings'
4. Near the bottom of the page, click the link "Choose default apps by file type"
5. Find the extension ".sln" or ".vcproj", and select the default application.

Comment: My solutions always opened by VS2017  and when I checked default application it was set to VS2017 and after changed it to Visual studio Version Selector my problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Visual studio could open normally the solution, but the version selector couldn't identify the version correctly.

In my case there was a problem with the EOL. Somehow the file was using unix EOL format, by changing it back to Windows format, the version selector started working again.

Answer (score 2):

Open your solution in the right Visual Studio version. Click your Solution to select it. Click File --> Save xxx.sln.

[image]