# How exactly does "Visual Studio Version Selector" chooses a Visual Studio version?

Tags: visual-studio

For extensions like `.sln` or `.csproj`, the default application is *Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector*. I've got two versions installed, 2010 SP1 and 2012 RC. How exactly will this application decide which VS to launch?

I would say that it works like this:

1. If it finds any hint in the given file which version should be used, then it uses it. For example, at the top of `.sln` files there is something like this so the Version Selector can decide:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

2. If it doesn't find any hint it will use whichever version was later installed (in my case I reinstalled 2010 SP1 after 2012 was already installed on my PC and now I think that VS2010 is opened more often than 2012 but am not 100% sure).

This is my feeling but what are the exact rules?

Comment: Not documented.  But you can safely assume it uses the version number in the file.

Comment: @HansPassant:  not what's happening on my system:  it **was** the right version, but when another version had a re-install of the TFS add-on, that version of Visual Studio started being the one to run.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are some version info in the file header. Otherwise it would not be possible for the file explorer to display different document icon on the .sln file with a number:

[image: VS2008]
[image: VS2010]
[image: VS2012]
[image: VS2013]
[image: VS2015]
[image: VS2017]
[image: VS2019]
[image: VS2022]
<sup>representing .sln files for VS versions 2008/2010/2012/2013/2015/2017/2019/2022</sup>

This number on the icon disappears if you edit the .sln file with notepad or some other text editor that does not preserve the UTF-8 signature (see [comment by Paul Groke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042636/how-exactly-does-visual-studio-version-selector-chooses-a-vs-version#comment44789916_12352910)). In this case also the version selector cannot choose the right version, and you cannot open it from the file explorer. You can specifically open it from within Visual Studio and save the .sln file to fix it. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2829550/109392) for more on this issue.

Comment: You can edit .sln files with a text editor that does preserve the UTF-8 signature (also incorrectly known as "byte order mark"). If the UTF-8 signature is not present, the version selector will ignore the contents of the file and just use the latest version to open it. I just tried this out on one of our "broken" .sln files - works like a charm. Opened it up in Notepad2, re-saved in "UTF-8 signature" format => works again. No need to re-save with VS. See accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804759/vslauncher-starts-wrong-version

Comment: @PaulGroke - The `byte order mark` (BOM) is the proper name of the `UTF-8 signature`.  It just happens that there is only one byte order for UTF-8.  But UTF-16 has 2 byte orders. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @awe - Don't forget to save the file with `CRLF` (Windows style line endings) not just `LF` (Unix style line endings).

Comment: @Jesse Chisholm AFAIK the proper name of U+FEFF is "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE". At least every character description entry for U-FEFF that I can find uses that name. Wikipedia should be updated ;) And using the old/alternative name "byte order mark", when not indicating byte order, feels strange to me.

Answer (score 5):

The .sln file must be a UTF-8-BOM file and it must start like this:

```
[blank line]
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version XX.XX[XXX...]
[description]
```

The `[description]` is for example `# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop` for VS 2012 or `# Visual Studio 15` for VS 2017.

The second line is case sensitive but the third line (`description`) is not. If it is missing, the Selector seems to start the latest VS.

The `VisualStudioVersion` entry is ignored.

However, for the right file icon to be displayed, the `[description]` has to be **exact** and case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Open your solution in the right Visual Studio version. Click to select the solution. Click File --> Save xxx.sln.

[image]