# Visual Studio start up to 2012 not 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I had installed vs2012 first and than I installed vs 2010. Now whenever I run the "devenv" or open any solution file It defaults to 2010.

How do reset this to run as vs2012 and not vs2010.

Any help greatly appreciated/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're meant to install VS in chronological order (i.e. the oldest first).

There are a couple of workarounds:

The first: Open VS2012, go Tools > Options > Environment > General > "Manage File Associations"

The second: Reinstall VS2012 in Repair mode.

Both should work.

Comment: Also, the behaviour of opening a solution file in VS2010 is by design, if the solution file is a VS2010 solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042636/how-exactly-does-visual-studio-version-selector-chooses-a-vs-version

Comment: Not quite what I asking.. What I am saying is start->run type in devenv then ok.. I want it to load vs2012 not vs2012. Without re-install.

Comment: `devenv` from your Run dialog is controlled by your PATH environment variable. Open the System control panel and edit your PATH so the VS2012 directory is before the 2010 one.

Comment: Works, also fixed one of my other issues I was having.. installing a third-party tool set was not registering the tool bar...