# visual studio 2017 unsupported file on a project built in VS 2017 - csproj issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, csproj

the issue i am having is, on a project i've been working on for a week, ONLY IN VS 2017, it now is unsupported. this is the error code i am getting:

> Unsupported
>
> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
>   For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
>        - theFileThatIsAnIssue.csproj"
>
> No changes required
>   These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
>        - MyProjectTitle, "C:\Users\meAsAUser\Desktop\MyProjectTitle\MyProjectSolution.sln"

I have gone through and deleted all .user files, tried cloning from my remote repo, opened the sln in notepad to make sure it was any CPU (it is), and restarted both VS and my computer.

it has now put the little "15" marker on all the solutions on my computer, which means this will be an issue for my other projects as well.

Comment: I would recommend doing a Repair of your VS 2017 installation via the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: What kind of project is it? Something can be opened in older VS, does not guarantee it can be opened in VS2017.

Comment: @MartinZikmund shall try, thanks. some of my versions are also suddenly coming up as vs12 that, again, were built using vs17.

Comment: @LexLi it is an MVC DB first project. and i do understand that, but these were projects built in VS17 that suddenly cannot be opened using VS17 and are now labeled as 15 and 12.

Comment: The icons showed in Windows Explorer is controlled by something called Visual Studio Version Selector, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042636/how-exactly-does-visual-studio-version-selector-chooses-a-vs-version/12352910 It should not prevent you from launching VS and then open it. Again, reinstalling Visual Studio 2017 might fix that.