# Choose specific VSTO-Version when opening TFS-Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I do have a TFS Project (TFS 2013) and I would like to set up my Visual Studio 2015 to work at that project. I have Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2015 installed. Now whenever I go to the main page of my Project and click "Open in Visual Studio" (like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/vsts/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs)), Visual Studio 2017 opens. I would like to have it open in VSTO 2015. How can I select which version of Visual Studio should open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution file should contain a UTF-8 signature that describes in which version the solution is to be opened. This is what's used for example to show [different icons for solution files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352910/997973) targeting different Visual Studio versions.

This signature info is also used by the Visual Studio Version Selector when opening a solution. An easy way to fix this is make sure that have the solution local on your dev machine and then right click -> open with and choose the Visual Studio Version Selector. Then pick the correct version of Visual Studio that you want to use.

[image: Use the Visual Studio Version Selector]

This will then be honored by your browser when opening a solution since this also uses the Visual Studio Version Selector.